# What are some problems in EXP not known to be EXPTIME-Complete, but also do not have any known algorithm in NP?

Tags: complexity-theory

These would be problems known to be in exp where there could hypothetically be a P or NP algorithm, but none have been discovered yet if one is possible.

Comment: The title doesn't match the body.  "not known to be in NP" is different from "there could hypothetically be a polynomial time algorithm, but none have been discovered yet if one is possible".  Please put the question in the body of the post.  The title should be a short summary.

Comment: @ D.W.♦
 I fixed it.

Comment: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/799/5038

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $NP\not= PSPACE$ and $PSPACE \not= EXPTIME$, all
$PSPACE$-complete problems are incomplete in $EXPTIME$

Answer (score 3):

Any [BQP-complete problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BQP) should suffice, since BQP is contained in EXPTIME but not believed to be contained in NP and not believed to be equal to EXPTIME.